# Consuming a restful API from Android app

Tags: android, node.js, rest, heroku

I have created a restful API that I have made using node.js and will deploy to Heroku. I want my android application to make requests to the web API. My understanding is that I will just have to send HTTP requests from the Android app using any external API that does the job. 
Is my assumption correct? 
Thank you

Comment: You could have googled .... This is not a good question. Either way, yes and preferably use a network lib like retrofit to communicate with your API

Comment: Use `Retrofit` (https://square.github.io/retrofit/).....and `gson` if applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you need to do API call to talk to your restful server . For this you can use any below implementation .

[Sending Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

[Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

[Retrofit Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

[Async Client Example](http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-asynctask-http-client-rest-example-tutorial)