# Sending image resource link to android via nodejs api

Tags: android, node.js, express

I want to send an image url to android using nodejs express server. my images are saved in /public/images. i will then use the link and view the image with android Glide library. the problem is, i don't know how to send the image url to android from nodejs express server. (src) For example.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.default)
        .error(R.drawable.default)
        .override(400, 400)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageView);
```

i want to know how to send the **imageUrl** from server to android.
More info
normally when i serve images with html,

```
<img src="/images/imagination_by_akiraalion-dawk529.jpg"/>
```

but i want to send the src to android. what is the format??

Comment: you need to call the Rest APIs from android to get the imageUrl from server.Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315586/consuming-a-restful-api-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

> i want to know how to send the imageUrl from server to android.

You need to create simple rest web service with the help of `Node.JS` then return required details as like image in your case in the response of this service in `JSON` format.

Later, you need to consume these API's in your android app and pass the URL into the `Glide` instance.

Comment: yes, i want to know the format of the image url. :D sorry for my late edit

Comment: my sample json object looks like this    {  name: "title", image:""  } i don't know what to put into the image property

Comment: simply URL of the image like `http://domain/images/imagination_by_akiraalion-dawk529.jpg`

Comment: i run with localhost so will it looks like this? {  name:"title", image:"'http://localhost:portnumber/images/imagination_by_akiraalion-dawk529.jpg'"  }

Comment: @GeorgethantZin Yep.  I don't think localhost will work. You have to give IP address of your server

Comment: okay. thanks for the url format :D. i will try with LAN and connect it with my laptop and phone and hope for the best. still studying :D  anyways, thanks man.